# Problema al instalar MySQL en Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu

Me aparece este problema cuando intento utilizar MySQL en un servidor virtual de Ubuntu:

```
  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
  '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Esa instrucción surge justo cuando coloco la instrucción sudo mysql. Que creen que pueda ser?

Comment: Asegúrate de que MySQL esté configurado para usar el socket correcto:
Asegúrate de que el archivo de configuración de MySQL (por lo general, /etc/mysql/my.cnf o /etc/my.cnf) tenga la ruta correcta del socket especificada. Debería verse algo como esto:
```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```
Verifica que la ruta del socket sea la correcta. Si no lo es, ajústala en el archivo de configuración

Comment: ... _o_ coloca opciones a mysql para que se conecte usando TCP al puerto adecuado.

Comment: Para ver si el puerto está abierto puedes usar el comando "nmap -p 3306 localhost" si no lo has arrancado en el puerto habitual (3306) hay que sustituir por el puerto correcto.